# SyncAdapter, Handling Local edits, and flags (DELETED, DIRTY, AND CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER)

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-syncadapter

- App syncs to a CalDAV server
- Uses the default Android calendar app along with a SyncAdapter

My problem is that I don't follow how the SyncAdapter deals with local edits.

- I have some logic in my SyncAdapter's `onPerformSync()` that pulls calendars and events from the server and saves it to the Android Calendar Provider.
- When I save the calendars (`resolver.insert()`), I append the `CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER` flag to the Calendars URI so I can store server information in relevant `CalendarContract.Calendars` fields.
- When I save events, I do not append the `CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER` flag.

What I want to achieve is on either a scheduled (*runs in background*) or manual (*user hits refresh in Android calendar app*) call to `onPerformSync()`, I want to be able to get any events that were locally edited or deleted on the device.  I can then push the changes to the server, while also pulling down server-side changes.

But how exactly do events and calendars get marked as `DELETED` or `DIRTY`?  Whenever I delete an event on a SyncAdapter calendar, it just removes it from the database without ever calling `onPerformSync()`.

I have looked at:
[How to use CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969522/how-to-use-caller-is-syncadapter-properly)
but I still do not completely understand.

Comment: Did you find some answers to theses questions?