# Disable ContentProvider notification while SyncAdapter is running

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I use a `ContentProvider` to handle my data, and an `AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter` to sync it. In my `SyncAdapter.onPerformSync`method, I use the `ContentProviderClient` parameter to add some data. However, when I update my data, my provider notifies the observers:

```
if (updateCount > 0)
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

The UI is refreshed, that's good, but… the sync adapter is notified too. And another sync is queued.

Is there any way to prevent this, ignoring (in the `SyncAdapter` only) the modifications done during the `onPerormSync` call?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange(android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver,%20boolean) last param

Comment: I noticed it. But as I'm not calling my `ContentProvider` directly, how am I supposed to toggle it?

Comment: look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969522/how-to-use-caller-is-syncadapter-properly